# AngularJS $resource RESTful example

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs

I would like to use $resource to call my RESTful web service, (which I am still working on) but I would like to find out if I got my AngularJS script correct first.

The todo DTO has: `{id, order, content, done}`

`:cmd` is so I can call `api/1/todo/reset` to clear the todo table in database.

Here is the code with comment of my understanding:

```
function TodoService($resource) {
    var src = $resource('api/1/todo/:id:cmd',
              {id: "@id", cmd: "@cmd"}, //parameters default
              {
                ListTodos: { method: "GET", params: {} },
                GetTodo: { method: "GET", params: { id: 0 } },                            
                CreateTodo: { method: "POST", params: { content: "", order: 0, done: false } },
                UpdateTodo: { method: "PATCH", params: { /*...*/ } },
                DeleteTodo: { method: "DELETE", params: { id: 0 } },
                ResetTodos: { method: "GET", params: { cmd: "reset" } },
              });

    //Usage:

    //GET without ID
    //it calls -> api/1/todo
    src.ListTodos();

    //GET with ID
    //it calls -> api/1/todo/4
    src.GetTodo({ id: 4 });

    //POST with content, order, done
    //it calls -> api/1/todo
    src.CreateTodo({ content: "learn Javascript", order: 1, done: false });

    //UPDATE content only
    //it calls -> api/1/todo/5
    src.UpdateTodo({ id: 5, content: "learn AngularJS" }); 

    //UPDATE done only
    //it calls -> api/1/todo/5
    src.UpdateTodo({ id: 5, done: true });

    //RESET with cmd
    //it calls -> api/1/todo/reset
    src.ResetTodos();
}
```

One particular thing I am not sure is the PATCH method, I don't want to update everything, can I update just one field? Am I constructing this piece of code correctly?

Comment: It looks like you're using $resource as a basic $http service. $resource is more for getting an object from a RESTful data source, manipulating it, then sending it back with `obj.save()`. You could do what you're trying to do with a basic $http implementation.

Comment: @blesh why shouldn't he use $resource when he wants to communicate with his RESTful webservice? As you said, isn't that exactly the purpose of it?

Comment: It looks for me but I would define the $resource as a service and inject it. This allows you to easily reuse it somewhere else later, if you need to.

Comment: @Flek Well, he *can* use $resource like $http if he *wants* to. But that's not really how it was meant to be used.

Comment: @Flek & blesh, I am learning how to use angular. constructing restful service is not a problem. I just wana to know what is the most efficient way to consume the rest/normal service at brower side. I do have an injection part, too.
var app = angular.module('app', ['todoModule']);
angular.module('todoModule', ['ngResource']).factory('todoService', TodoService);
Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: @blesh So, is the problem with what he's doing that the resource is too heavily customized / not RESTful enough?

Comment: Well, it's not really a "problem", per say. It's more that he's not taking any advantage of the RESTful api and all the stuff that $resource can do for you out of the box.

Comment: So what is the @ in the parameter doing?

Comment: @piotr, at @ sign usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559515/what-is-id-as-passed-to-resource

Answer (score 212, accepted):

$resource was meant to retrieve data from an endpoint, manipulate it and send it back. You've got *some* of that in there, but you're not really leveraging it for what it was made to do.

It's fine to have custom methods on your resource, but you don't want to miss out on the cool features it comes with OOTB.

**EDIT**: I don't think I explained this well enough originally, but `$resource` does some funky stuff with returns. `Todo.get()` and `Todo.query()` both *return* the resource object, *and* pass it into the *callback* for when the get completes. It does some fancy stuff with promises behind the scenes that mean you can call `$save()` before the `get()` callback actually fires, and it will wait. It's probably best just to deal with your resource inside of a promise `then()` or the callback method.

#### Standard use

```
var Todo = $resource('/api/1/todo/:id');

//create a todo
var todo1 = new Todo();
todo1.foo = 'bar';
todo1.something = 123;
todo1.$save();

//get and update a todo
var todo2 = Todo.get({id: 123});
todo2.foo += '!';
todo2.$save();

//which is basically the same as...
Todo.get({id: 123}, function(todo) {
   todo.foo += '!';
   todo.$save();
});

//get a list of todos
Todo.query(function(todos) {
  //do something with todos
  angular.forEach(todos, function(todo) {
     todo.foo += ' something';
     todo.$save();
  });
});

//delete a todo
Todo.$delete({id: 123});
```

Likewise, in the case of what you posted in the OP, you could get a resource object and then call any of your custom functions on it (theoretically):

```
var something = src.GetTodo({id: 123});
something.foo = 'hi there';
something.UpdateTodo();
```

I'd experiment with the OOTB implementation before I went and invented my own however.  And if you find you're not using any of the default features of `$resource`, you should probably just be using `$http` on it's own.

### Update: Angular 1.2 and Promises

As of Angular 1.2, resources support promises. But they didn't change the rest of the behavior.

To leverage promises with `$resource`, you need to use the `$promise` property on the returned value.

#### Example using promises

```
var Todo = $resource('/api/1/todo/:id');

Todo.get({id: 123}).$promise.then(function(todo) {
   // success
   $scope.todos = todos;
}, function(errResponse) {
   // fail
});

Todo.query().$promise.then(function(todos) {
   // success
   $scope.todos = todos;
}, function(errResponse) {
   // fail
});
```

Just keep in mind that the `$promise` property is a property on the same values it was returning above. So you can get weird:

#### These are equivalent

```
var todo = Todo.get({id: 123}, function() {
   $scope.todo = todo;
});

Todo.get({id: 123}, function(todo) {
   $scope.todo = todo;
});

Todo.get({id: 123}).$promise.then(function(todo) {
   $scope.todo = todo;
});

var todo = Todo.get({id: 123});
todo.$promise.then(function() {
   $scope.todo = todo;
});
```

Comment: First, thanks very much for answering my question. I studied the code from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2433-Using-RESTful-Controllers-In-An-AngularJS-Resource.htm  and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6KITGRQujQ&feature=channel&list=UL  is there a chance you can take a look and tell me if they are better off using $http instead?

Comment: I guess I'll refine my statement like so: If you're not using *any* OOTB features of $resource, then you're just taking up memory with object and function references you don't need. Is it going to hurt anything? Probably not. But it may be more efficient to just use $http if you're just doing standard CRUD operations and not leveraging $resources neato features.

Comment: Blesh, are there any docs that go over OOTB functionality?  The angular docs are confusing.

Comment: Sadly, there's not, really. I've been just digging through their source on GitHub.

Comment: @blesh, Can you explain the comment about CRUD?
Looks to me like CRUD is exactly the basic operations supported by $Resource OOTB: if RESTful means mostly "POST, PUT, DELETE" etc'.

Comment: yeah, that was a little non-specific. I meant to say that if you're not GETting the same model thing POSTing it back in the same format, $http is probably a better choice. In other words, if you're getting arbitrary models, and posting back unrelated models, or even parts of those models.

Comment: Doesn't `Todo.get({id: 123});` return a promise and not a straight up object?

Comment: @IngóVals - Not directly, to get the promise to a resource, you need to use the `$promise` property. This is newer functionality than this example... I'll update the answer.

Comment: @blesh, can you add an example to get a list ?

Comment: @IlyasMimouni, for a list, you'd just use `Todo.query()`. There's an example with the promise part above. I'll see what I can do to show that.

Comment: Thank you. Offical AngularJs documentaion is poor for about using  restful service..

Comment: Perhaps you can help me with my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405569/how-to-save-my-result-as-indexed-array.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do `$scope.todo = Todo.get({ id: 123 })`.  `.get()` and `.query()` on a Resource return an object immediately and fill it with the result of the promise later (to update your template). It's *not* a typical promise which is why you need to either use a callback or the $promise property if you have some special code you want executed after the call. But there is no need to assign it to your scope in a callback if you are only using it in the template.