# How can I send a DELETE Http Verb with the rowId when using ng-grid and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have set up the following resource, function and cell template:

```
var Exam = $resource('/api/Tests', {}, {
    saveData: { method: 'PUT' }
});
$scope.delete = function (row) {
    row.entity.$delete(row.examId);
}
$scope.updateEntity = function (column, row) {
    console.log(row.entity);
    console.log(column.field);
    row.entity.$saveData();
}

{ field: '', cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="delete(row)">Delete</button>' }
```

However I find that it is only sending:

```
   DELETE /api/Tests HTTP/1.1
```

Is there a way I can change the resource so that if the row testId is equal to one then it correctly sends

```
   DELETE /api/Tests/1
```

Note that I already tried the following but it still sends the same URL to my server:

```
   row.entity.$delete(row.entity.testId)
```

One more thing. My updateEntity works and sends a put along with a json of the row

Comment: shouldn't it be row.$delete ?

Comment: @njzk2 - thanks. Just tried that and I get the message: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '$delete'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change the url in for your resource like this:

```
var Exam = $resource('api/Tests/:id, {id:'default value here'});

Exam.$delete({id:1});
```

Or redefine the delete action:

```
var Exam = $resource('api/Tests, {}, {
    $delete: {
        method: 'DELETE',
        params: {id: 'some value here'}
    }
});
```

Have a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275194/1036025

Comment: Thanks this looks good but the value of 'some value here' would be different. If i redefine the delete action then how could I change the calling function to set the value?

Comment: I added a link to a similar question that may help you!

Comment: The parameters sent when calling the $delete function will override the values of those specified (ie: Exam.$delete({id:1})). I think that the first option is sufficient.