# How to integrate Rails views with angularjs ng-view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have created rails view (ERB). However, I want to integrate it into angularjs `$routeProvider`, but I don't know what url should I fill into `templateUrl` to give me the appropriate rails view. For example, I tried:

```
$routeProvider.when('/pages/foo', {
templateUrl: "/pages/foo",                  
controller: "PageFoo"
                })
```

But the result appears as a blank page.
Are the two features even integrateable? Or do I have to create new `.html` files, instead of using preexisting `.html.erb`

Comment: I have angular handling my Rails app, so its possible. You just have to create routes

Comment: @apneadiving, can you give me an example? I tried templateUrl: "/pages/foo", and i have pages#foo, but ng-view doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 15):

Angular js provides its own routes. rails routes will always be used when you want to connect your views with database(CRUD). that is data binding with angular.js now i will show you how to use it with rails...

I want to add new user using angular js views and list all users. i will use rails as backend to store users in database so i will create user_controller

1. First Create resource of user. we will not create any views so be carefull for that

   ```
   rails g resource user name:string
   ```
2. Then go to route.rb and check there is a route created, and create Home controller with index action that we will use as our single page application where our output will be yield.

   ```
   rails g controller home index
   root to: "home#index"
   ```
3. type this command on terminal where you will see our 7 routes. we never use new and edit method, because new and edit don't respond to json.

   ```
   rake routes
   ```
4. Now we want all user with a unique name so go to create_user migration and uncomment this line and then we will migrate the database.

   ```
   add_index :users, :name, unique: true
   rake db:migrate
   ```
5. Now modify our controller so that all data fetching and insertion will be done with json format. so put this code inside users_controller.rb, if you are using rails 4 then follow this otherwise not. attributes will be adjustable in model.

   ```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
     respond_to :json

     def index
       respond_with User.all
     end

     def create
       respond_with User.create(user_params)
     end

     private
       def user_params
         params.require(:user).permit(:name)
       end
   end
   ```

   Its time to use angulajs in our rails application
6. Go to application.html.erb replace  tag line with this

   ```
    <html ng-app="userApp">
   ```
7. Now add angular.js file in asses/javascripts, download it from http://angularjs.org/
8. Now we will create a controller to handle our angular application routes to know then that this controller wants something from me. so type this on terminal

   ```
   mkdir -p app/assets/javascripts/angular/controllers
   ```
9. Now let's create the controller file itself. I'm calling this controller the "userCtrl", Thus our filename will be
       app/assets/javascripts/angular/controllers/userCtrl.js.coffee
10. In controller userCtrl

    ```
    app = angular.module("userApp", ["ngResource"])

    @userCtrl = ($scope, $resource) ->
      User = $resource("/users", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})
      $scope.users = User.query()

      $scope.createUser = ->
        user = User.save($scope.newUser)
        $scope.users.push(user)
    ```

    (This will insert new user record into database, by creating createUser method)
11. Create a view for taking input from user write this code in home/index.html.erb.

    ```
    <div ng-controller="userCtrl">
      <form ng-submit="createUser()">
        <label>Enter Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter user name" ng-model="newUser.name" />
        <button ng-click="createUser()" class="button tiny">Submit</button>
      </form>


      <!-- List all usres -->
      <h4 ng-show="users.$resolved && users.length > 1">All users</h4>
        <span ng-repeat="c in users">
          {{c.name}}<br>
        </span>
    </div>
    ```

Run application and watch output.

Answer (score 1):

In this [page](http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/04/23/angularjs-on-rails-4-part-2/), it gives a 'Hello World' example of scaffolding Angularjs + Rails. (Please ignore the extra parts for additional functions.) When you type any name,then get a Hello message displayed for him, you've got a functional Angularjs + rails app.

A couple of points to share:

- A simple way to include angular.js file:

  1. Put `gem 'angularjs-rails'` in your Gemfile;
  2. Then put `//= require angular` in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file.
  3. Very likely you will need `//= require angular-resource` so that you can use ngResource services to access the RESTful API provided by rails applicaiton from server end. [See this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13275194/2197555) for examples.
- Include Rails-controller-specific javascript codes in layout this way:

  1. Add the following codes to `app/views/layouts/applications.html.erb` file after the line `<%= yield %>`:

     ```
     <%= page_specific_js = "#{params[:controller]}_#{params[:action]}" %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag page_specific_js if Rails.application.assets.find_asset page_specific_js %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag  page_specific_js if Rails.application.assets.find_asset page_specific_js %>
     ```
  2. Remove `//= require_tree .` from application.js.
- Include the following codes in config/initializers/assets.rb for precompiling js and css files:

  ```
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
    if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
      full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
      app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
      if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
        puts "including asset: " + full_path
        true
      else
        puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
        false
      end
    else
      false
    end
  end
  ```