# Redirects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller action: create which is responding to json format and html.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @pr.save
    format.html {redirect_to(some_path)}
    format.json {render json: @pr, status: :ok}
  else
    format.html {}
    format.json {}
  end
end
```

So from a angular service I send a post request to this action, if it is successful I would like to redirect the user to `some_path` in my server log I see that redirect bing made, but the page is not changing.

How can I fix this? I am using turbo links as well so I would like not loading all the files again.

Comment: You should redirect your user on client side, with `window.location`, for example.

Comment: what about reloading the assets?

Comment: What do you get in the http response in the browser network inspector

Comment: i get the created object, header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Turbolinks you can do:

1. Set a location in your controller:

   format.json {render json: @pr, status: :ok, location: some_path}
2. Get the location from your header response in js:

   header('Location')
3. Use Turbolinks visit:

   Turbolinks.visit(header('Location'));

And now you are not loading the assets.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a route where you want to redirect your user. Then In controller You can call the page

```
if( <Your Condition true/false> )
   $location.path('/dashboard');
```

remember you should have added dependency $location in your controller
Or you can take a look here :

[How to integrate Rails views with angularjs ng-view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514669/how-to-integrate-rails-views-with-angularjs-ng-view/20822893#20822893)