# What is the best way to install Angular on Rails 4?

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angular-fullstack

I have populated api using Rails and now wish to mount a front-end framework like Angular on Rails. I've seen people using Gulp or Grunt to do this, but still not 100%. Would love to see how experts efficiently stack Angular and Rails together. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get AngularJS on Rails is pretty straight forward, especially if you are using Rails as the API source.

1. Add the gems below to your Gemfile:

   `gem 'bower-rails'
   gem 'angular-rails-templates'`
2. Next do `bundle install` to install the gems.
3. Create a folder in your `app/assets` folder called `templates`. This is where you will keep your AngularJS html templates.
4. Place your package.json and bower.json at your project root.
5. Create a folder called `client-test` as you already have a `test` folder for your rails api - right?!
6. Ensure that your `package.json` references your `client-test` folder correctly.

The pertinent `scripts` section should look like this:

`"test": "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start client-test/karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start client-test/karma.conf.js  --single-run",`

7. For testing you are going to need to use `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor` to convert the templates in your app/assets/templates folder.

That's it. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks Harold. Do you use a task manager like Grunt or Gulp to do this?

Comment: Yep! For my ROR API project, I use Grunt for linting and occasionally to live reload my SCSS files when I am tweaking aspects of UI.

Answer (score 1):

Angular js is javascript framework to build single page application. when you think to use it with rails your front-end will be angular js and back-end will be postgresql or mysql and to connect database with front end you should have rails to handle request comes from user side. Response of the data will always be JSON. you just need to handle JSON data on front.

It means that your controller will just give JSON response. for that you should have only controller and model.

So take a look here, This will guide you through the angular js + rails binding, Its a good combination to use and love to use ever.

[How to integrate Rails views with angularjs ng-view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514669/how-to-integrate-rails-views-with-angularjs-ng-view)

https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/

Comment: Much appreciated SSR. The links are awesome!

Comment: @Ji Lee : Thanks. Accept answer if use full to you. 